# Laravel | How to know the Request url comming from

Tags: laravel, routes, request

**hello**

i have a form that i can run from different blade but pointing on same Controller

after submiting data i want to know the url or route comming from it the request and then redirect user to an other route

```
public function store(Request $request) {

 $request = $request->all();
 $new = App\Model::create($request);
 $new->save();

 if ( Request comming from url or route x ) {
     return redirect()->back();
 } else {
      return redirect()->route('route');
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `url()` helper for that, which will give you the current request url:

```
url()->current();
```

or

```
// Without Query String...
$url = $request->url();

// With Query String...
$url = $request->fullUrl();
```

Comment: url()->current() give me the action url
url()->previous() give me tha previous url ( http://example.com/previous 
the two last one give me this error  `Call to a member function fullUrl() on array
` 
i want to compare the previous url  to redirect users

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: I also had a hard time understanding what his intentions are. But here is what I understood in the end: he has two routes that each serve a form. Both of the forms submit the data to the same, third route. He then needs to know in the controller action of the third route from what route the data was coming from.

Comment: sorry the problem is with my english , i will work more on it , sorry

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
        if ( app('router')->getRoutes()
                          ->match(app('request')
                          ->create(URL::previous()))
                          ->getName() 
                          == 
                          'factures.create') {

        return redirect()
            ->back();
    } else {


        return redirect()
            ->route('clients.index');
    }
```